# The page isn't redirecting properly spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, web.xml

Hi I am trying to integrate spring security in my project after integrating when I am trying to login I am seeing this below error 
[image]

Here is my web.xml and spring-security.xml files

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

Enable this after correcting spring security
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Logging listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring Security disabled enable after correcting spring security-->
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
          org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<filter>
   <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Image</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.property.servlet.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Image</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<!-- Mappings that do not require security (authentication/principal object is not available for these urls)-->
<!-- Pattern should start with /web . Patterns like /login,/home are not effected -->

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter"  />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>

<!-- loginFormUrl pattern is /login -->
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.property.controller.auth.PropertyAuthenticationProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager">
        <beans:ref bean="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl">
        <beans:value>/j_spring_security_check</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:ref bean="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:ref bean="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService">
    <beans:bean class="com.property.controller.auth.UserAuthenticationService" />
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.property.controller.auth.PropertyUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultPortalTargetUrl">
        <beans:value>/home</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.property.controller.auth.PropertyUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultPortalFailureUrl">
        <beans:value>/login?error=1</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="targetUrlParameter">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.DEFAULT_TARGET_PARAMETER"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref='daoAuthenticationProvider'/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">       
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService">
        <beans:bean class="com.property.controller.auth.UserAuthenticationService" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="saltSource">
        <beans:ref bean="saltSource" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder">
        <beans:ref bean="passwordEncoder" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.property.controller.auth.PasswordEncoder">
    <beans:property name="encodeHashAsBase64">
        <beans:value>false</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- aop:advisors(preauth and postauth...) configuration  -->
<beans:bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"   class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions">
        <beans:value>false</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="propertySecurity" class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" />
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="saltSource" class="com.property.controller.auth.SaltSource">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="securityMetadataSource" class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

 </beans:beans>
```

Here I am having two issues:

1. when I type localhost in my browser its redirecting to localhost/login (where should i change to redirect to /home)
2. when its redirected to login page I am getting the above error

can any once help me in resolving this issue

Comment: add `/home` as `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"` if you not want to login to see `/home`.

Comment: Even after changing its redirecting to /login and getting same problem

Comment: enable spring security debug and post log message.

Comment: Besides the logs, it would also be helpful to see what is going on  on the network. If you can, use Firebug or Chrome dev tools and show us the network requests and responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your app URL if its app/login

change your 
    `<intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />`

This worked for me
Cheers!